# Removing default routing in symfony causes internal server error

Tags: php, routes, symfony1, doctrine, jobeet

Error Message:
The route "default" does not exist.

Yes, it doesn't exist. But as described in the Doctrine version of  ["Practical Symfony | Day 5"](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/05) everything should work well when default routing is removed, because all actions of the job module has been successfully routed by other routers.

I get the error when I request the URL below which is routed by a router other then the default one.
...jobeet.localhost/frontend_dev.php/job/sensio-labs/paris-france/1/web-developer

I'd be glad, if anyone would help me solving this issue. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that no route has been associated with this URL, please provide some code. Please check `JobeetJob.class.php` for some typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you still have something referencing the 'default' route in your application or template code, maybe in a redirect, link_to or url_for function call.  If you could post the first few lines of the stack trace I can be more specific.

Comment: Thanks Cryo!
I had a url_for function call referencing to the default route in a template. Fixed it!
Bests.